# Real time live streaming with an iPhone for robotics

Tags: objective-c, sockets, video-streaming, vlc, robotics

For a research purpose, I developed and app to control a wheeled mobile robot using the gyro and the accelerometer of an iPhone. The robot has a IP address, and I control it by sending messages through a socket. Since the robot has to be controlled from anywhere in the world, I mounted a camera on top of it. I tried to stream the video from the camera using the http live streaming protocol and vlc, but the latency is too high (15-30sec) to properly control it.

Now, vlc has the possibility to stream over udp or http, but the point is how do I decode the stream on the iPhone? How should I treat the data coming into the socket in order to visualize them as a continuous live video?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. You are already streaming via http and you want udp? Is that it?

Comment: No I am already streaming using the apple draft protocol http live streaming, and it does not work for my purposes. Therefore I want to use the capability vlc has to stream via udp, but MPMoviePlayerController does not have this capability. It's like if had to build a new movie player to handle the incoming stream. I looked at ffmpeg and the iFrameExtractor project, but I didn't have any luck.